# How to make exe file version readable to all editions of windows system

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe2, fileversioninfo

I have 32 bit program written in c++ builder xe2, which have dynamicly linked bpl files. 
My program update system is based on exe file version. But in some of clients witch windows 2008 serwer 32 bit update system failed, because program see 1.0.0.0 file version instead of 2.3.0.94. When I check properities of file in this windows it shows 1.0.0.0 also.

How to compile exe file to be sure that version will be readable to all editions of windows system?

Answer (score 3):

Your project likely has multiple **Build Configurations** and you did not define version info in all of the configurations that you compile for.  With the introduction of Build Configurations and Option Sets, defining version info has become harder to manage, because users expect to define version info once and have it automatically carry through the various configurations, but that is simply not the case.  Users typically have to either duplicate their version info multiple times as needed, or use third-party tools or IDE addons to handle it for them.  This is a known shortcoming in Embarcadero IDE versions of recent years, and there are countless discussions about it in the Embarcadero forums.

Comment: I have version info compiled into exe from rc file and i use only one build configuration. Problem is with one and the same compiled exe file on different windowses. On windows 2008 server it has version 1.0.0.0 on other windows ( XP, 7 ) it has correct version 2.3.0.94.
Program is running but becouse of wrong version of file it tried to automaticly update again and again.

Comment: Using an .rc file is probably the root of your problem. Have you tried defining the version info in the project itself instead? In any case, a version resource operates the exact same way on all Windows versions. It is not possible for one version of Windows to display the proper information and another version of Windows to ignore it. I know for a fact that Windows 2008 does not treat version resources differently. I have VCL apps that display their version info just fine on Windows 2008, but I don't use .rc files to define version info.

Comment: Double-check your .exe file with a resource viewer, such as ResHacker or XN Resource Editor.  Make sure the version resource is actually present and accurate.

Comment: [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/) can be used to help manage the version info (although if your description is correct, that is not the problem)

Comment: I've checked with ResHacker as @RemyLebeau said, and it turn out that both, wrong and correct version was present there. I think when project file was recreated some time ago, someone probably forgot to uncheck option "include version information in project". 
Strange that diffrent version of windows see difftent versions of file, but maybe it is because windows that see 1.0.0.0 have different language than we and most of our clinets have.

Comment: Using an rc file is the way to go. This lets you retain control of the version info and does not tie you to the ide.